Matlab code to generate the Phase and angle of the sinusoid?
I have been trying to generate the positive ,negative and zero sequence components of the input sinusoid .I have three sinusoidal phases 120 degree separated (Balanced) . The formula to calculate Positive , Negative and zero sequence is given below.

where a = 0.5 + i0.866 or  1<120* (complex number).
Now if i generate Va , Vb , Vc inside of a matlab itself and use the formulae I get the correct result. Code below and correct result too .
% Define Parameters
t = 0:0.001:1; % Time vector
A = 1;         % Amplitude
f = 50;        % Frequency in Hz

% Generate Sinusoidal signals with 120 degrees phase shift
v_a = A * exp(1i * (2 * pi * f * t));  % V_a = A * e^(j * 0)
v_b = A * exp(1i * (2 * pi * f * t - 2 * pi / 3)); % V_b = A * e^(j * 120°)
v_c = A * exp(1i * (2 * pi * f * t + 2 * pi / 3)); % V_c = A * e^(j * -120°)

% Call the function to calculate sequence components
[va_pos, va_neg, va_zero] = fcn(v_a, v_b, v_c);


% Plotting the sequence components
figure;

% Plot for Positive Sequence Component
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t, real(va_pos), 'r', 'DisplayName', 'Real Part'); 
hold on;

title('Positive Sequence Component');
xlim([0 0.3]);
ylim([-1 1]);
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend show;
grid on;

% Plot for Negative Sequence Component
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t, real(va_neg), 'r', 'DisplayName', 'Real Part');

hold on;
%plot(t, imag(va_neg), 'b', 'DisplayName', 'Imaginary Part');
title('Negative Sequence Component');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylim([-1 1]);
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend show;
grid on;

% Plot for Zero Sequence Component
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t, real(va_zero), 'r', 'DisplayName', 'Real Part');
hold on;
%plot(t, imag(va_zero), 'b', 'DisplayName', 'Imaginary Part');
title('Zero Sequence Component');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylim([-1 1]);
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend show;
grid on;

% Function to calculate sequence components
function [va_pos, va_neg, va_zero] = fcn(v_a, v_b, v_c)
% Define complex exponential for 120 degrees and 240 degrees
alpha = complex(-0.5, 0.866);         % e^(j*120 degrees)
alpha_square = complex(-0.5, -0.866);  % e^(j*240 degrees)

% Calculate positive sequence component
va_pos = (1/3) * (v_a + alpha * v_b + alpha_square * v_c);

% Calculate negative sequence component
va_neg = (1/3) * (v_a + alpha_square * v_b + alpha * v_c);

% Calculate zero sequence component
va_zero = (1/3) * (v_a + v_b + v_c);
end


Now I have Va , Vb , Vc (I generate them now in simulink using sine wave block)and use them as inputs to the simulink function written below (same as one written above).
function [va_pos, va_neg, va_zero] = fcn(v_a, v_b, v_c)

% Define complex exponential for 120 degrees and 240 degrees
alpha = complex(-0.5,0.866);         % e^(j*120 degrees)
alpha_square = complex(-0.5,-0.866);  % e^(j*240 degrees)

% Calculate positive sequence component
va_pos = (1/3) * (v_a + alpha * v_b + alpha_square * v_c);

% Calculate negative sequence component
va_neg = (1/3) * (v_a + alpha_square * v_b + alpha * v_c);

% Calculate zero sequence component
va_zero = (1/3) * (v_a + v_b + v_c);

end
It gives wrong result as show below .(First plot is Positive sequence , second is negative seq. and third is zero sequence . same as the above mentioned plot).

and i suspect it is because it is taking the Va , Vb and Vc in real time (in simulink model).
I tried abs() and phase() to extract the phase and magnitude of the sinusoidal wave separately(in real time function in simulink) but to no avail . I would like to know if there is a way of doing extracting a phase and magnitude of a sinosoidal wave in real like in simulink using MATLAB scripting ?

I don't know what the "sinusoid" is here, but for complex numbers the functions are abs and angle, not phase, according to the doc.

Please define clearly what you mean by "It gives wrong result", you should provide a [mre] with input and output data for this function only, if that is where you think the error is.

Edited it . Hope the question is more clear now.

One way to obtain those three wrong subplots is if (in your correct code) your input data has only the real component, that is, if your replace exp(1i * by sin(, or just take real of v_a, v_b, v_c; can you verify that you have generated the complex sinusoidal signal?

Thank you . Figured it to be the issue .

The error in me not being able to recreate the waveforms like in those subplots was that i was only adding the real part of the complex sinosuidal waveform .
In order for me to extract the waveform I used "PLL block" (to get the frequency 'f') and clock (to get the time values) .
Then the code goes as follows.
function [va_pos,vb_pos,vc_pos,va_neg,vb_neg, vc_neg,   va_zero,vb_zero,vc_zero,va_reconstructed,vb_reconstructed,vc_reconstructed] = fcn(t, f, va_in, vb_in, vc_in)

% Calculate the phase-shifted voltages
v_a = va_in * exp(1i * (2 * pi * f * t));               % V_a = A * e^(j * 0)
v_b = vb_in * exp(1i * (2 * pi * f * t - 2 * pi / 3));  % V_b = A * e^(j * 120°)
v_c = vc_in * exp(1i * (2 * pi * f * t + 2 * pi / 3));  % V_c = A * e^(j * -120°)

% Define complex exponential for 120 degrees and 240 degrees
alpha = exp(1i * 2 * pi / 3);          % e^(j * 120 degrees)
alpha_square = exp(-1i * 2 * pi / 3);  % e^(j * 240 degrees)

% Calculate positive sequence component (full complex value)
va_pos = (1/3) * (v_a + alpha * v_b + alpha_square * v_c);
vb_pos = alpha_square * va_pos;
vc_pos = alpha * va_pos;

% Calculate negative sequence component (full complex value)
va_neg = (1/3) * (v_a + alpha_square * v_b + alpha * v_c);
vb_neg = alpha * va_neg;
vc_neg = alpha_square * va_neg;

% Calculate zero sequence component (real part)
va_zero = (1/3) * (v_a + v_b + v_c);
vb_zero = va_zero;
vc_zero = va_zero;

% Reconstruct the original signal (optional)
% This can be done to check if va_in ≈ va_pos + va_neg + va_zero
va_reconstructed = va_pos + va_neg + va_zero;
vb_reconstructed = vb_pos + vb_neg + vb_zero;
vc_reconstructed = vc_pos + vc_neg + vc_zero;

end
Now after you reconstruct . For plotting the real time values you can plot using real() in time domain.
I was plotting using real and then reconstrucing using the real part as well (That was the error) .
Thank you for the help .
